# linear layout is not working in android.got error of The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed

Tags: android

this is a code of linear layout in android but when i tried to use multiple linear layout i got error of "The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed".

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_message "
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message"/>

<Button 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send"
    android:onClick="sendMessage" />
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />



</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout >

    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_message1 "
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mission the parent for your layout, you can't have 2 roots on your layout, they need to be inside another Layout or the last LinearLayout need to be inside your root Layout